# Insert Statement Combination logic

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Ok so I'm using C# to insert information into a table in a database server. It creates the SQL command based off of a bunch of if statements that add to it. I'm having an issue getting the statement to be created cleanly. I understand that to combine Insert statements in SQL Server we use:

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
SELECT 'value1', 'value2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'value3', 'value4'
UNION ALL 
SELECT
etc
```

My issue is ordering them so that the statement will work regardless of which if statements it passes. For example,

```
function()
string sqltext = "INSERT INTO myTable"
if(cond1)
{ sqltext=sqltext + "SELECT 'v1', 'v2' UNION ALL" }
else if (cond2) {
sqltext = sqltext + "SELECT 'v3', 'v4' UNION ALL" }
```

In this case, if either condition returns by itself, the statement won't work because the statement will end in UNION ALL. I hope this makes sense. Thoughts?

Comment: This sounds like a potential SQL Injection vulnerability.  Proceed carfully... http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: Please stop doing it that way before your code ends up on the daily wtf. Write a stored procedure or use an ORM. http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Enterprise_SQL.aspx

Comment: This code is completely for internal uses, so it will only be accessed by an admin anyway. But thank you. I will keep this in mind for the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a list of selects

```
string sqltext = "INSERT INTO myTable";

List<string> selectList = new List<string>();
```

and

```
if(cond1)
{
    selectList.Add("SELECT 'v1', 'v2' UNION ALL");
    ...
```

and finally

```
string selectStatement = string.Join(" UNION ALL ", selectList.ToArray());
sqltext = sqltext + " " + selectStatement;
```

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion, but perhaps the OP is not using C# 4.0?

Comment: @Fish, what does C# 4.0 have to do with anything?  `string.Join` has been around since .NET 2.0.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo `string.Join()` has been around since .net 2.0 besides where does he say he's not using c# 4.0?

Comment: @Bala R: My mistake. I looked up string.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>) in the docs. That overload has only been around since 4.0.

Comment: This is great and I have no doubt that it works, but the compiler is refusing to get around the fact that sqltext isn't a complete statement when it compiles. Is there a way around this? The code gives me a syntax error when the command.ExecuteNonQuery is outside the if statements but is fine when it's inside.

Comment: @Aeonstrife Is it a compile time error or a runtime exception? if it's runtime-exception, you can inspect what sqltext is at runtime by setting a break point. Can you post what it is?

Answer (score 1):

Remove " UNION ALL" from sqltext after it's generated.

```
                if(sqltext .Trim().EndsWith("UNION ALL")) {
                    sqltext = sqltext.Remove(s.LastIndexOf("UNION ALL"));
                }
```

Also, as a side note, I would recommend using `StingBuilder` instead of doing string concatenation using `+`.